# Shortcut to Highlight Duplicates in Sublime Text 3

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3

So, the highlighduplicate plugin for sublime text does not seem to work for me so I'd like to create my own. I need this to identity duplicates so it's a step further than Sublime's 'Permute: Unique'

I've created a regex expression: `^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$` that will find duplications and it seems to work well.

Now, all I need is quick keyboard shortcut to trigger it. I tried recording a macro (using cmd+i) but it didn't seem to take even after multiple attempts.

I know sublime packages are written in python but I'm not well-versed in Python.

How would I write this plugin/package?

Thanks,

Comment: It's been a long time since I played with plugins. But at the very least, here is some tips.
You can install [AAAPackageDev](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AAAPackageDev), it will provide the `new plugin` command, that will give you a raw skeleton in python.
You can then create a shortcut to trigger the python command.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight duplicates? Is my plugin suitable for you? Or maybe I misunderstood here #_#

If it's not perfectly suitable for you, you can check out the code, it's quite easy~

[CursorWordHighlighter](https://github.com/ownself/CursorWordHighlighter)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the package for you, got [here](https://github.com/Xaelias/HighlightDuplicates) and install this new version.
Let me know if you have any issue, but apparently it works on my laptop.

To be a little more verbose, there was two issue with the file. First, a change in ST API made a call to add_regions() fail, and there was also a change in python API regarding defaultDict implementation.
You can look at the modification I made on github, or here is a quick diff:

```
diff --git a/hightlight_duplicates.py b/highlight_duplicates.py
similarity index 91%
rename from hightlight_duplicates.py
rename to highlight_duplicates.py
index 8351275..c2e6137 100644
--- a/hightlight_duplicates.py
+++ b/highlight_duplicates.py
@@ -42,7 +42,9 @@ def filter_counts(counts, treshold=1):
     lower or equal to the treshold, which defaults to 1.
     '''
     filtered = dict()
-    for k, v in counts.iteritems():
+    # for k, v in counts.iteritems():
+    for k in counts:
+        v = counts[k]
         if len(v) > treshold:
             filtered[k] = v
     return filtered
@@ -60,11 +62,13 @@ def show_lines(regions, view):
     all_regions = []
     for r in regions:
         all_regions.extend(r)
-    color_scope_name = settings.get('highlight_duplicates_color',
+    color_scope_name = settings.get('highlight_duplicates_color', \
                                         DEFAULT_COLOR_SCOPE_NAME)
-    view.add_regions('DuplicatesHighlightListener',
-                        all_regions, color_scope_name,
-                        sublime.DRAW_OUTLINED)
+    view.add_regions('DuplicatesHighlightListener', \
+                        all_regions, \
+                        color_scope_name, \
+                        "Packages/Theme - Default/dot.png", \
+                        sublime.DRAW_NO_FILL)


 def highlight_duplicates(view):
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this Xaelias. I gave it a shot it didn't seem to work. Here's what the console spit out: `  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 271, in on_modified
    callback.on_modified(v)
  File "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/HighlightDuplicates-master/highlight_duplicates.py", line 107, in on_modified
    highlight_duplicates(view)
  File "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/HighlightDuplicates-master/highlight_duplicates.py", line 81, in highlight_duplicates

Comment: show_lines(duplicates.values(), view)
  File "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/HighlightDuplicates-master/highlight_duplicates.py", line 71, in show_lines
    sublime.DRAW_NO_FILL)
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime.py", line 861, in add_regions
    sublime_api.view_add_regions(self.view_id, key, regions, scope, icon, flags)
TypeError: String required

Comment: @user2544542 It's weird, I don't get this error...
Did you modify the settings file? If not, did you try with a simple file (like twice the same line?). It is to try and find what causes this issue... I also pushed a slight modification to the git repository. Try it, maybe it's that simple.